Laravel Pennant: Error when running php artisan tinker
I've just installed Laravel Pennant v1.12.0 on Laravel 10.15.0. When I run php artisan tinker it gives me this error, "The "pennant:purge|pennant:clear" command cannot be found because it is registered under multiple names". I have no idea what the problem is and how to fix it. Appreciate your help!

This is a bug in the framework and is fixed in v10.48.4, see https://github.com/laravel/pennant/issues/117
